What is the Analytic Form of the Beam Wave Function, Near the Slit Boundary Line, in the 2D Quantum Mechanics Double Slit Experiment
Consider the famous quantum mechanics double slit experiment, in 2D.
Let the origin of coordinates be at the source of the beam so that the $y$ axis is orthogonal to the detector display screen of the experiment (the screen that detects and displays the interference pattern). Let the barrier/boundary that contains the two slits be a line at $y = y_0$ and locate the detector display screen at $y = y_1 > y_0$.
Assume potential $V(x, y_0) = \infty$, except at the x-ranges of the two very small slits, where $V = 0$ (assume the slits are very small compared to the wavelength of the incident beam wave function, $\Psi$).
Then the beam wave function must have a value of zero at every point on the $(x,y_0)$ line (except possibly at the slits). However, we also know that the wave function must be pointwise continuous, even when there is an infinite potential in the problem. Therefore, $\lim_{y \to y_0} \Psi (x,y) =0$ (again, possibly with the exception of the x ranges of the slits).
At $y_1 > y > y_0$, a simple approximation of the wave function is as the interference between two circular waves, denoted as $i = 0$ and $i = 1$. Hence, at $y_1 > y > y_0$, $\Psi = \Psi_{i=0} + \Psi_{i=1}$. For each wave, we can imagine a local polar coordinate system, $(r_i,\theta_i)$, with origin at the slit associated with wave $i$. $\theta_i$ ranges from $0$ to $\pi$, where, at values of $0$ and $\pi$, the wave is being evaluated at $y_0$. The most physically likely solution would be for $\lim_{\theta_i \to 0} \Psi_i =0$ and $\lim_{\theta_i \to \pi} \Psi_i =0$.
My question is what is $\Psi_i$ as a function of $\theta_i$ so that $\Psi_i (\theta_i) \to  0$ as $\theta_i \to 0$ or $\pi$?

For $y>y_0$, perhaps the approximation of the wave function, $\Psi$, as the sum of two offset circular waves is only good at the “far-field”, i.e., close to $(x,y_1)$, and $\Psi$ at $y=y_0+dy$ (at the extremely near-field, with differential dy also being very small compared to wavelength) is more complicated. Then, my question is what is that extremely near field, pointwise continuous, wave function that also satisfies the boundary condition $\Psi=0$ at $y_0$? Maybe the Rayleigh-Sommerfeld optics solution is correct (but, not the Fresnel integral, which is near-field but assumes $y>>y_0+dy$)
